# order by a certain character

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

let's suppose we have a certain table containing a 'name' column with the following rows:

```
'A'
'K'
'_C'
'_B'
```

is there a way to order it alphabetically and placing the names that come with an underscore '_' first (alphabetically too) using ORDER BY on MySQL? so the output would be:

```
'_B'
'_C'
'A'
'K'
```

Comment: its exactly the same you would normally do. ORDER BY [field]

Comment: according to the ascii chart http://www.asciitable.com/, `'_'` (95) is less than `'a'` (97) so it will by default come before it alphabetically. however `'_'` (95) is greater than `'A'` (65) so capital will come first. Essentially `'A' < '_' < 'a'`.

Comment: thank you for pointing that, @LoganMurphy . it was my mistake to put the characters on lower case. edited.

Comment: @LoganMurphy the 'ORDER BY' does not sort acording to the ascii code. It uses a dictionary-type sort order.

Comment: @DanielAndré would you happen to have an article i can look at to review this dictionary-type sort? thanks in advance

Comment: @LoganMurphy From Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38689_01/pt853pbr0/eng/pt/tgbl/concept_UnderstandingSortOrders-076968.html

Answer (score 1):

```
order by 
       case when substr(mystring, 0,1) = '_' then 0 else 1 end
       , mystring
```

(not tested, but you get the idea)

i.e. you first order on whether or not the string starts with the character '_' or not, and then on the string itself.

As others have pointed out, your example renders this unecessary, but this is how you would do it in general. For instance, you could order all 5-character words first in a similar way:

```
order by 
       case when length(mystring) = 5 then 0 else 1 end
       , mystring
```

Comment: a simple order by will have the same result since '_'<a

Comment: @Daniel: that's why I qualified my answer to show how you could adapt this for other cases.